# Why does form data look like this?

Tags: httprequest

This comes from Chrome Network inspector, the URL looks normal

[image]

However, the form data looks strange, is it some kind of encryption?

[image]

```
q: blurb!659695|blurb!659696|blurb!659696|blurb!659695|blurb!659695|blurb!659695|blurb!659695|blurb!659695|blurb!659694|blurb!659694
```

### [image]

Note: the link is only available for signed in user and cannot sign up by users themselves.

Comment: Are you trying this on proxy website?

Comment: You say "the URL looks normal", but note that it consists of a single standard parameter `?c=` with a value containing a pipe-separated list of key-value pairs. This is all custom data generated by some front-end application, and I doubt there's much anyone could say about "why" it looks that way.

Comment: @AnkurR Does "proxy website" mean something like postman?